# In slit experiment: is it one wave function before and two wave functions after the split?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, interference, double-slit-experiment, superposition

Forgive my round-about background to the question: I'm curious how the experiment "fires electrons slowly that interact with themselves"... I'm thinking that's just a simplification?

I feel there's a few analogies given alongside this experiment which are useful to a point but begin to confuse. When they "generate electrons" are they not exciting the electron field with energy? And they're doing it in some sort of reasonably uniform way over a period of time that satisfies a "wave function"? Im guessing they're not "pulsing" energy to create a "single electron" at a time which = "a single ripple taking an unknown path on a wave function". I doubt we have that much control over the electron field?

Isn't superposition just the fact we can't define and predict how the electron field will interact, we only know through the wave function where it's likely to interact, and we call that "superposition" because it's useful to think of "an electron" being everywhere at once, but that's only an analogy: there isn't any such thing as "an electron" and superposition is just a useful analogy?

So electrons don't really interfere with themselves: energy waves do. And I would think the slits themselves are a form of detector as they're altering the original wave function and creating two new ones?

Comment: Here is a numerical integration of the Schrodinger equation for the wave equation through a double slit (the wave function is just one before and after and forever: evolution is unitary!): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPWoggFedtY&ab_channel=ThomasBronzwaer

Comment: There are 2 well known types of DSE; 1) where light is used ... like Thomas Young who used light from a window 2) more advanced where electrons are fired in a vacuum (like in an old fashioned TV called a CRT (cathode ray tube)) .. the electrons move because high voltages are applied to the plates.

Answer (score 2):

> When they "generate electrons" are they not exciting the electron field with energy?

I get the impression that you are thinking of electrons as being like water waves - you put energy into the water to create waves. This is indeed something like how quantum field theory thinks of electrons (simplifying grossly), but it is not how they are "generated" in the double-slit experiment.

Electrons have a 'rest energy' associated with their existence as excitations of the electron field, and they also have a 'kinetic energy' associated with their movement through space. (There is also more to them than just 'energy' - there is also their charge and spin and other properties.)

Atoms have electrons in them already - we don't need to provide any rest energy to create them. What we do is to heat a piece of metal full of electrons until they have enough kinetic energy to escape the surface, and then use an electric field to accelerate them towards the slits. It's more like we have a box full of waves and we raise their kinetic energy until a few escape from the box. We can adjust the energy we provide until the number escaping is so low that there is only one electron in the system at a time.

> And they're doing it in some sort of reasonably uniform way over a period of time that satisfies a "wave function"?

No. The electrons obey a wave function all the time - it's what they are. Heating a lump of metal full of electrons to release a few doesn't change that. The wave is not created by what we are doing.

> Im guessing they're not "pulsing" energy to create a "single electron" at a time which = "a single ripple taking an unknown path on a wave function". I doubt we have that much control over the electron field?

No. We do not impose any pulsing to create single electrons. Electrons are singular already. It is part of the peculiar nature of quantum physics - they are both particles and waves at the same time. They act like a wave when you are not looking, and like a single point-like particle when you do.

> Isn't superposition just the fact we can't define and predict how the electron field will interact, we only know through the wave function where it's likely to interact, and we call that "superposition" because it's useful to think of "an electron" being everywhere at once, but that's only an analogy: there isn't any such thing as "an electron" and superposition is just a useful analogy?

No. The rate of release of electrons can be slowed down to the point that there is usually only one in the apparatus at a time. When it hits the screen at the other end, it appears as a single point-like dot. However, on the way to the screen it acts like a wave. We can predict exactly how it will interact, and where the peaks and troughs of the wave will be. When we observe it, it appears randomly, with a probability equal to the squared amplitude of the wave.

'Superposition' is something else. The wave equation has the special property of being *linear*, which means that if two separate waves are both solutions of the equation, then adding them together gives another wave which must also be a solution of the wave equation. Put more simply, if we drop two pebbles in a pond, the resulting wave is the sum of the two waves from each pebble. It looks like the ripples cross each other without interacting. This 'adding up' is called 'superposition'. We superpose two sets of ripples to get a combination.

> So electrons don't really interfere with themselves: energy waves do.

No. Electrons really do interfere with themselves.

> And I would think the slits themselves are a form of detector as they're altering the original wave function and creating two new ones?

No. It's still one wave function, corresponding to one electron. It's just that the shape of the single wave function emerging from two slits is the *sum* (superposition) of the waves you would get from each slit individually.

The slits are not a detector in the quantum-mechanical sense - if they were, the wavefunction would collapse to a point-like dot at the slits, thus could only go through one slit at a time, and you would get one broad blurry band on the screen with no interference stripes. That's not what happens.

--

Electron do not act entirely like classical water waves, or classical particles. It is not a case of normal, sensible classical wave behaviour being explained in a 'simplified' way to make it sound weird. It really *is* weird!

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate you spending the time to methodically go through my question (and my other pseudo questions!)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking the the problem "single electron scattering on two slits of given width and given distance apart", which is an experimental situation, through the mathematics of quantum field theory , as if the mathematics come before the experimental numbers.

Here is a [single electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles) at a time double slit experiment.

[image: snglele]

The footprint looks as if a particle passed and interacted with the screen. The interaction is local, not spread over all.

Accumulating electrons one sees the interference pattern arising, which can be fitted with a simple wavefunction for the electron going through the slits, whose $Ψ^*Ψ$  can be "calculated with QED or with simple quantum mechanical approximations. It is an effect not expected from macroscopic particles.

Comment: I don't get how they say they're sending single particles through the slits: if they're particles, then the interaction has already happened and the wave function has collapsed? I get they can detect one particle at a time but I don't get how they can send one particle at a time and still consider it the same wave function as the next electron. But thanks I'll try to read more on it. Where you write "Ψ∗Ψ" does that mean the answer is there are two wave functions after the splits?

Comment: Simon I have given a hittachi link that describes the original experiment and has a link to video. as far as "consider it as the same electron". that is not the way quantum mechanics works. There must be the same boundary conditions and the same energy/momentum four vector of the projectile. Then one can accumulate and see the predicted probability  for the experiment.

Comment: "Where you write "Ψ∗Ψ" does that mean the answer is there are two wave functions after the splits? –" No, it is one wavefunction describing the particular boundary conditions and particles interacting with them.it is the probability given by the wavefunction calculation to find the particle at (x,y,z,t).see the  wavefunction postulate http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html

Comment: When the boundary conditions are the same and the four-vectors of the particles are the same, then one can accumulate and find the **probability** for the interacions to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone in trying to imagine some common-sense explanation for the 'two slits' effect, but I am afraid you are deluding yourself if you think you can invent an explanation that has eluded the best minds in physics when you have only a vague notion of the the subject. That said, I applaud you for trying.

There are a number of misconceptions suggested by your question. That might be unintentional on your part, and simply the result of the every-day language you have used, but we should clarify them anyway.

Firstly, the sort of experiments that test interference of particles do not 'create' electrons. The electrons already exist- the experiments are designed to release the electrons so that they can move freely through space.

Secondly, experimenters have developed techniques that allow them to say with confidence that only one electron at a time is passing through the interferometer.

Thirdly, a wave function is not something that is created under certain conditions by the experimenters. A wave function is a mathematical device used in quantum theory to explain and predict the behaviour of quantum systems. It seems reasonable to suppose that the mathematical wave function corresponds with something physically real, but quite what has not been established yet.

Fourthly, you say there isn't any such thing as 'an electron'. There is endless evidence to suggest that is completely wrong.

Fifthly, you say the screen containing the two slits acts as a detector. In one way you are right, but in an important way you are stating something irrelevant.

Sixthly, you say the slits 'create two new wave functions'. That shows a mis-understanding of what a wave-function is. To take a classical analogy, consider a two-slits experiment performed in a ripple tank. From one end of the tank come parallel ripples which meet a screen containing two slits. One the other side of the screen you find an interference pattern where the ripples emanating from the two slits interact. Is the interference patter the result of a single ripple interacting with itself or of two ripples interacting? The answer to that question is meaningless, as the words are simply different ways to describe the same result. In the case of the experiment with electrons, there is one wave function for the electron, which is the sum of two separate components, one from each slit.

When we talk of super-positions, all we mean is that the wave function can be represented as a sum over a set of over functions. It is rather like saying that a dollar is a superposition of a hundred cents. Or to take a more relevant physical example, consider a vibrating guitar string which you have plucked at random. The string will vibrate in a complicated pattern which is mathematically equal to a superposition of other simpler patterns of vibration.

Finally, if you want to understand why the two-slits experiment is still so perplexing, you should bear in mind that it works with lots of different types of particles, including electrically neutral massless photons, charged particles such as electrons, massive neutral particles such as neutrons, and even large complicated molecules. Also, the effect doe not seem to depend upon the material from which the slits are cut.